# Why does this if always return true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking for string inside of a div element using jquery but it allways returns the if never the else even when the dom doesn't contain then $ what stupid mistake am i making?

```
$('.bw-switcher').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('toggledrate', 1000);
    $('.toggledrate > .bwswitch-button:before').toggle('fast');
    $('.toggle_rates').toggle('fast');
    if ($(".deatils.dailyPrice:contains($)")) {
        $('.deatils.dailyPrice').toggle('fast');
        console.log('I am the if');
    } else {
        console.log('I am the else');
        $('.deatils.dailyPrice').toggle('fast').prepend('$');
    }
    $('.toggledrate > .bwswitch-button:after').toggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: Because `{}` is always equal to true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `$(".deatils.dailyPrice:contains($)")` is an object and not null objects are always evaluated as `true` in `if` tests.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) :

> Any value that is not undefined, null, 0, NaN, or the empty string
>   (""), and any object, including a Boolean object whose value is false,
>   evaluates to true when passed to a conditional statement

You probably want

```
if ($(".deatils.dailyPrice:contains($)").length) {
```

Comment: thank you you are completly right!! so which is the more elegant solution using length as you have suggested or size > as @esalija suggests?

Comment: `size` is deprecated and [jQuery recommends length](http://api.jquery.com/size/).

Comment: Ok point taken answer accepted!

Comment: Yes srry I left the comp...

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery function constructs a jQuery object. Objects are always considered true in a truthiness evaluation such as `if`.

Try this

```
if( $(".deatils.dailyPrice:contains($)").length > 0 )
```

Comment: Note that size is deprecated : http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: @dystroy thank you, that was completely surprising and unreasonable